# how to use i18n on a dynamic data with an array?

Tags: react-native, react-i18next

I wanna change the languages of my array but i don't know how to do with i18n i already change the static data and everything is working well.

i need to translate my element.nomClub

Now this is the function i wanna translate :

```
 renderMesClubs = () => {
    return this.state.sport.clubs
      .filter((choix) => {
        return choix.ligue == this.state.click;
      })
      .map((element) => {
        return (
          <View>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={async () => {
                await AsyncStorage.setItem('ChoixClub', element.nomClub),
                  this.props.navigation.navigate('Subscribe');
              }}>
              <View
                style={{
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                  marginHorizontal: 20,
                }}>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    color: 'white',
                    marginTop: 30,
                    marginBottom: 30,
                    fontSize: 35,
                    textAlign: 'center',
                    fontFamily: 'Ambit-Black',
                  }}>
                  {element.nomClub}
                </Text> 
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use interpolation:

```
//in React component
/.../
  <Text>
    {t('myValue', {value: element.nomClub})}
  </Text>

//in .json
"myValue": "{value}"
```

There are more information [about interpolation in the docs](https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component)